# Mageplaza Call to undefined method getCollectionClone()

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud, mageplaza

I am encountering the following problem with Magento and the Mageplaza plugin:

```
Call to undefined method Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::getCollectionClone() at /app/app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php:179)"
```

This is the code snippet in the Price.php file:

```
/** @var Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
->getCollectionClone()
->setGetAllData(true)
->removeAttributeSearch(['price.from', 'price.to'])
->setGetAllData(false);
```

If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to Update the Mageplaza Module Because, in the new version, they update the code.**

```
protected function _getItemsData()
{
    if (!$this->_moduleHelper->isEnabled()) {
        return parent::_getItemsData();
    }
    $attribute = $this->getAttributeModel();
    $this->_requestVar = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
    if ($this->_filterVal) {
        /** @type Collection $productCollectionClone */
        $productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
            ->removeAttributeSearch(['price.from', 'price.to']);
    }
    $facets = $productCollection->getFacetedData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
    $data = [];
    if (count($facets) >= 1) { // fix range of price with elasticsearch
        foreach ($facets as $key => $aggregation) {
            $count = $aggregation['count'];
            if (strpos($key, '_') === false) {
                continue;
            }
            $data[] = $this->prepareData($key, $count);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Here is the latest code of **_getItemsData()** Function.

Answer (score 1):

For me with magento 2.4.6 and Porto Theme i had to use for Price.php line 179
In addition to Ronak Rathod post.
this github post [m2-layered-navigation-v2.3.0-v2.3.1-patch.sh](https://github.com/mageplaza/m2-layered-navigation-releases/blob/master/m2-layered-navigation-v2.3.0-v2.3.1-patch.sh) 
Where replace product slider config lines 175 to 203

```
   */
public function getSliderConfig()
    {
        /** @var \Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
 
        if ($this->_filterVal) {
            /** @type \Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollectionClone */
            $productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
            ->removeAttributeSearch(['price.from', 'price.to']);
        }

    $min = $productCollection->getMinPrice();
    $max = $productCollection->getMaxPrice();

        list($from, $to) = $this->_filterVal ?: [$min, $max];
        $from = ($from < $min) ? $min : (($from > $max) ? $max : $from);
        $to = ($to > $max) ? $max : (($to < $from) ? $from : $to);
 
        $item = $this->getItems()[0];
 
        return [
            "selectedFrom" => $from,
            "selectedTo"   => $to,
            "minValue"     => $min,
            "maxValue"     => $max,
            "priceFormat"  => $this->_taxHelper->getPriceFormat(),
            "ajaxUrl"      => $item->getUrl()
        ];
    }
```

Comment: same scenario... 2.4.6 Porto Theme. Those lines of code solved my problem. Thanks for posting and the link back to the github codebase. Cheers,